# trying insert a checkbox in a form of terms and condition

Tags: php

I am trying to input a check-box for terms and conditions in a form, but when I registered the form without ticking the box the registration went through , (which was not suppose to be). Please help have a look.

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Register</h2>";

$submit = $_POST['register'];
//form data
$fullname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['fullname'])));
$username = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['username']))));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['password'])));
$repeatpassword = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword'])));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email'])));
$houseno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['houseno'])));
$addressa = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['addressa'])));
$addressb = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['addressb'])));
$addressc = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['addressc'])));
$county = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['county'])));
$state = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['state'])));
$country = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['country'])));
$accept = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['accept'])));

if ($submit)
{
$namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM reusers WHERE username='$username'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

if($count!=0)
{
die("Username already taken!");

}


//check for registration form details
    if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword&&$email&&$houseno&&$addressa&&$county&&$state&&$country)
{
if($accept!= 1)
{
if ($password==$repeatpassword)
{
//check char lenght of username and fullname
if (strlen($username)>25||strlen($fullname)>25)
{
echo "Lenght of username or fullname is too long";
}
else
{

//check password length

if(strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
{
echo"Password must be between 6 and 25 characters";
}
else
{
//check password length
$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM reusers WHERE email='$email'");
$ecount = mysql_num_rows($emailcheck);
if($ecount!=0)
{
echo"email already registered Please sign in into your account to continue";
}
else
    {
       //generate random code
       $code = rand(11111111,99999999);

   //send activation email
   $to = $email;
   $subject = "Activate your account";
   $headers = "From: donotreply@reacheasy.co.uk";
   $body = " Hello $fullname,\n\nUsername $username,\n\n Password $password ,\n\nYou registered `and need to activate your account. Click the link below or paste it into the URL bar of your browser\n\nhttp://reach.co.uk/activate.php?code=$code\n\nThanks!";

   if (!mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
       echo "We couldn't sign you up at this time. Please try again later.";

else

{

//register the user!
//encript password
$password = md5($password);
$repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);


$queryreg = mysql_query("

INSERT INTO reusers VALUES ('','$fullname','$username','$password','$email','$code','0','houseno','addressa','addressb','addressc','county','state','country')

");

die("You have been registered successfully! Please check your email ($email) to activate your account<a href='index.php'>Return to login page</a>");
}
}
}
}
}
else
    echo"Your passwords do not match!";

}
else
    echo"Please read and accept Terms and Conditions before registering!";
}
else
        echo "Please fill in <b>all</> fields!";

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your checkbox?

Comment: <div>
 <input name="accept" type="checkbox" class="tickbox" value="1" />
 <a href="termsandcondition.php">Terms and Conditions</a>
 </div>

Answer (score 1):

```
$accept = ($_POST['accept'] ? 1:0);
```

Comment: since it was part of the form i thought it will be posted along with the $submit = $_POST['register'];
or is it different

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
if($accept == 1)
```

because `$_POST['accept'] = 1` when you check the checkbox.
Now return `Please read and accept Terms and Conditions before registering!` when checkbox is checked and register the user when checkbox is not checked.

Comment: it is working , but i used this if($accept!= 1), is there a difference

Comment: `$accept != 1` is true if $accept is not 1 and `$accept == 1` is true only `if $accept = 1`. In your case `$accept=$_POST['accept']=1` when checkbox is checked and in other case it's missing.